# Static analysis error when using custom 3rd party component in Angular project

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-aot

I have an Angular (2+) datepicker component ([link to Github](https://github.com/IckleChris/ic-datepicker)) that I am currently using in two Angular projects

1. Angular CLI v1.0.0-beta.30, Angular v2.3
2. Angular CLI v1.0.0, Angular v4.0

App 1 works perfectly, both during development using `ng serve` and when building using `ng build -prod --aot`. App 2 however throws the following error both when attempting to serve and build;

```
ERROR in Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Calling function 'makeDecorator', function calls are not supported. Consider replacing the function or lambda with a reference to an exported function, resolving symbol NgModule in /path/to/angular4-app/node_modules/ic-datepicker/node_modules/@angular/core/src/metadata/ng_module.d.ts, resolving symbol NgModule in /path/to/angular4-app/node_modules/ic-datepicker/node_modules/@angular/core/src/metadata.d.ts, resolving symbol NgModule in /path/to/angular4-app/node_modules/ic-datepicker/node_modules/@angular/core/src/core.d.ts, resolving symbol NgModule in /path/to/angular4-app/node_modules/ic-datepicker/node_modules/@angular/core/index.d.ts, resolving symbol IcDatepickerModule in /path/to/angular4-app/node_modules/ic-datepicker/dist/src/ic-datepicker.module.d.ts, resolving symbol IcDatepickerModule in /path/to/angular4-app/node_modules/ic-datepicker/dist/src/ic-datepicker.module.d.ts

ERROR in ./src/main.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './$$_gendir/app/app.module.ngfactory' in '/path/to/angular4-app/src'
 @ ./src/main.ts 4:0-74
 @ multi ./src/main.ts
```

My assumption based on [this Github issue comment](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/4647#issuecomment-285349444) is that the version being used in app 1 above did not perform the static analysis required to trigger this error.

What would cause this error to occur?

**Edit**

So I've just tried copying the library, stripping it right back to a module and a component that does nothing but output a `<h1/>` element and try that and the exact same error occurs ([link to the stripped back version](https://github.com/IckleChris/example-library)).

I came across [this page](https://medium.com/@isaacplmann/making-your-angular-2-library-statically-analyzable-for-aot-e1c6f3ebedd5) and looked into the points there, namely point #8. I moved the Angular dependencies to be `peerDependencies` (you can see that in the second repo above) but that has not fixed the error.

Comment: Possibly it's a fresh issue with interfaces [#15640](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/15640)...

Comment: Tried removing the usage of `@Inject()`, same error sadly, not sure if it otherwise affects

Comment: Is your 2nd project updated from CLI 1.0.0 Beta and Angular 2.3 or a new project? Because it's easy to break a project when upgrading.

Comment: Brand new @Ploppy, literally a `ng new`, NPM install the component and add it to the `app.component.html`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of digging and trial and error I found the answer. In my question edit I refer to [this page](https://medium.com/@isaacplmann/making-your-angular-2-library-statically-analyzable-for-aot-e1c6f3ebedd5) and claim that moving the Angular dependencies to `peerDependencies` in `package.json` does not fix the issue. This however was not true as I was using `npm link` to test the library within a new Angular project.

I believe the reason Angular's dependencies should be `peerDependencies` and not `dependencies` is because errors occur when `node_modules/ic-datepicker/node_modules` contains `@angular/*` dependencies. Moving Angular into peer will instead use the app-level `@angular` deps preventing this error.

As a side note for anyone who may be testing their local versions of a library, if you have your `@angular` dependencies added to `devDependencies` for usage during development, run `npm link -production` instead of just `npm link` to prevent the development deps from being installed.